# 19.04 Switch user option is gone

Tags: 19.04, switch-user

As a logged in user I no longer have the option in the righthand menu to switch users.

Why was this removed? Is there anyway to get it back?

Comment: Not an answer, but a way how to easily switch between users: GDM stays open on TTY1, so you can switch to the login screen with `ctrl+alt+f1` and then new user will be opened on next free TTY, `ctrl+alt+f2` is the first logged in user, `ctrl+alt+f2` the next one. Like this, you can directly switch between the TTYs / users.

Comment: bug related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1825544

Answer (score 0):

it's ctrl+alt+f7 on my bionic box to get back to the first user